# MSSQL Reach the limit and update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the query where if count the member table is reach to total 200. And trigger the UPDATE to other tables to close the status. 
example :

```
select count (member) as total from memberG group by member
```

--- if member total is not reach to 200 then ignore .

if member is reach to 200.

trigger UPDATE statement .

```
UPDATE table set status = 'close' where camid = '112'
```

Comment: What you are describing is a trigger on `memberG` not a query.

Comment: i am apologize that not clearly decribe . cuz i am still new in this area .

Comment: i have the campaign is like this. only limit only for 200 members who qualify can claim this free gift. once qualify member is reach to limit . and to trigger to close the campaign .the above query is an example.thanks

Comment: "And trigger the UPDATE to other tables to close the status. example :" this is not a query PER DEFINITION. Queries are RETRIEVING data, they NEVER change data. SELECT does and can not update anything - it asks, queries, filters, returns the data. UPDATE, i.e., is not a query but part of SQL DML.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use conditional then you should create a procedure or trigger not a query depending on the particular DBMS that you are using.
You can see a helpful tutorial on creating triggers here:
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/

Comment: Hi David , i use MSSQL

Comment: Very helpful tutorial here on how to create triggers:
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/